# Checkbox statistics in nested headings

Tags: org-mode

I would like to see a summary of checkbox statistics in next items within subheadings.  In the following example the subheadings update when I check or uncheck a checkbox. However, the top heading stays at "[0/0]".  Is there any way to collect statistics at that level as well? I would expect it to say "[5/9]" in this case.

```
* Top heading [0/0]
** Subheading one [2/3]
- [X] something that I need to do
- [ ] something that I need to do
- [X] something that I need to do
** Subheading two [2/3]
- [X] something that I need to do
- [ ] something that I need to do
- [X] something that I need to do
** Subheading three [1/3]
- [ ] something that I need to do
- [ ] something that I need to do
- [X] something that I need to do
```

Comment: In Org terms your subheadings are tasks and your checkboxes are subtasks, so if you add TODO keywords to your subheadings, your level-1 statistics (`[/]` or `[%]`) should update accordingly.

Comment: I know this is not what you want, but you could use the [`org-checkbox-statistics-hook`](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#mark-done-when-all-checkboxes-checked) hook to mark your subheadings as DONE whenever all checkboxes are completed (and vice versa). This would keep your level-1 statistics updated according to the number of TODO/DONE entries and not according to the number of boxes checked in the subtree.

Comment: @jagrg Yes, you're correct. That's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function counts the number of boxes checked in the subtree, and the second one updates the value accordingly.

```lisp
(defun count-statistics ()
  (let (num den end)
    (save-excursion
      (while (org-up-heading-safe) nil)
      (setq end (save-excursion
                  (org-end-of-subtree t)
                  (point)))
      (while (re-search-forward ".*\\[\\([0-9]*\\)\\(?:%\\|/\\([0-9]*\\)\\)\\]" end t)
        (push (string-to-number (match-string 1)) num)
        (push (and (match-end 2) (string-to-number (match-string 2))) den)))
    (setq num (apply #'+ (butlast num))
          den (apply #'+ (butlast den)))
    (format "[%s/%s]" num den)))

(defun update-statistics ()
  (let ((count (count-statistics)))
    (save-excursion
      (while (org-up-heading-safe) nil)
      (when (re-search-forward "\\[\\([0-9]*\\)\\(?:%\\|/\\([0-9]*\\)\\)\\]" (point-at-eol) t)
        (replace-match count)))))

(add-hook 'org-checkbox-statistics-hook 'update-statistics)
```

Answer (score 1):

I find these things work best if you don't mix'n'match different types of org headings. If you stick to using lists, then you can make each subheading a 'checkbox task' by putting in `[ ]` at the start of the item like so:

```
* Top heading [/]
- [ ] Subheading one [2/3]
  - [X] something that I need to do
  - [ ] something that I need to do
  - [X] something that I need to do
- [ ] Subheading two [2/3]
  - [X] something that I need to do
  - [ ] something that I need to do
  - [X] something that I need to do
- [ ] Subheading three [1/3]
  - [ ] something that I need to do
  - [ ] something that I need to do
  - [X] something that I need to do
```

When you now mark subtask two of subheading two as complete, that should update to this:

```
* Top heading [1/3]
- [-] Subheading one [2/3]
  - [X] something that I need to do
  - [ ] something that I need to do
  - [X] something that I need to do
- [X] Subheading two [3/3]
  - [X] something that I need to do
  - [X] something that I need to do
  - [X] something that I need to do
- [-] Subheading three [1/3]
  - [ ] something that I need to do
  - [ ] something that I need to do
  - [X] something that I need to do
```